# C# Form Controls

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form containing many picture boxes named pb_a1,pb_a2,pb_a3...  and so on..

I have a String array containing the picture box names. What I need to do is access each of these and specify an image for it.
Instead of hard coding, I would like to know if there is any way by which I can write a loop which gives me commands like

> ```
> > Form1.pb_a1.Image=<some Image>;
> > 
> > Form1.pb_a2.Image=<some Image>;
> > 
> > Form1.pb_a3.Image=<some Image>;
> > 
> > Form1.pb_a4.Image=<some Image>;
> ```

Comment: I think you would help yourself greatly in the future by stopping now and reading some beginner coding guidelines and tutorials. pb_a1 etc is not a particularly accepted naming convention for example.

Comment: @MrEdmundo: I think this was a logic question not a coding style question. There are many many coding conventions, all of them valid in some context.

Comment: @Nick I agree it is a logic question which is why I didn't put my comment as an answer. But my point remains.

Comment: @MrEdmundo: pb_a1 etc were just examples...   I am not a very good coder, but I follow some guidelines...   :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use the [ControlCollection.Find( )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) method on the forms `Controls` property?

Comment: That is what I'm doing right now, but unfortunately I have too many controls in the form and shuffling thru each of them is increasing time complexity to unacceptable levels.

Comment: But doesn't the Find() method allow you to search child controls too?

Answer (score 0):

if you only have the name of the picture controls and not a reference to them ( which I think you could have kept in a dictionary with name and reference when you created those controls earlier in the form... ), the only way you have I think is to search in the Form.Controls collection until you find the one with the name you are looking for and which is of the picture box type.

Comment: Have you trid ImageList?  For your scenario, you will have to loop the Form.Controls and compare names...

Comment: Is there no possibility of creating something like a macro which creates the required statements?? Since searching Controls Collection is to time consuming

Answer (score 0):

You're better off storing the picture boxes in a picture box array, rather than a string array.

```
PictureBox[] myPictures = {pictureBox1, pictureBox2, pictureBox3, pictureBox4};

foreach (PictureBox picture in myPictures)
{
    picture.Image = <some Image>;
}
```

If you *have* to have it as a string, the following code may help you out. Please note that I haven't included any error checking incase the element doesn't exist. You're likely to just get an empty element in that part of the array. You may want to encase it in try/catch as well.

```
string[] myPicturesString = {"pictureBox1", "pictureBox2", "pictureBox3", "pictureBox4"};
            PictureBox[] myPictures = new PictureBox[myPicturesString.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < myPictures.Length; i++)
            {
                foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
                {
                    if (c.Name == myPicturesString[i])
                    {
                        myPictures[i] = (PictureBox) c;
                    }
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show(myPictures[1].Name);
```

Comment: The code is at such a level now that I cannot change the picture boxes into an array. And I am using the second solution already. Any other way??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that these picturebox are fields of your form, you can reflect (System.Reflection) on the form class, retrieve a reference to the picturebox fields and store them into a dictionary. Do that during form creation (after InitializeComponent).

Next time you have to access a picture box by its name, just use:

```
myDictionary["pictureboxname"].Image = blabla;
```